# Reading from two files

Tags: python, csv, iteration

I am trying to write a script that will take several 2 column files, write the first and second columns from the first one to a result file and then only the second columns from all other files and append them on.

Example:

```
File one                         File two
Column 1     Column 2            dont take this column      Column 2
Line 1       Line 2              dont take this column      Line 2
```

The final result should be

```
Result file
Column 1    Column 2    Column 2     
Line1       Line 2      Line 2
etc
```

I have the almost everything working except for adding the second columns onto the first.  I am taking the ResultFile as r+ and I want to read out the line that's there (the first file data) and then read the corresponding line from the other files, append it, and put it back in.

Here's the code I have for the second section:

```py
#Open each subsequent file for 2nd column data
while n < i:
    with open(FileNames[n], "r") as InputFile
        with ResultFile:
            Temp2 = ResultFile.readline()
            for line in InputFile:
                Temp2 += line.split(",", 1)[-1]
                if line == LastValue:
                    break
            if len(ResultFile,readline()) == "":
                break
        YData += (Temp2 + "\n")
    n += 1
InputFile.close
```

The break IFs are not working quite right atm I just needed a way to end the infinite loop.  Also LastValue is equal to the last x column value from the first file.

Any help would be appreciated

**EDIT**
I'm trying to do this without itertools.

Comment: It doesn't look like you are opening your files properly. Read up on that first.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to open up all the files first and store them in a list.

```
fileHandles = []
for f in fileNames:
    fileHandles.append(open(f))
```

Then you can just readline() them in order for each line in the first file.

```
dataLine = fileHandles[0].readline()
while dataLine:
     outFields = dataLine.split(",")[0:2]
     for inFile in fileHandles[1:]:
          dataLine = inFile.readline()
          field = dataLine.split(",")[1]
          outFields.append(field)
     print ",".join(outFields)
     dataLine = fileHandles[0].readline()
```

Comment: I have opened the ResultFile at the beginning of the code, whole thing is under the with(open) of the ResultFile as r+

Comment: Not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: I see where you are opening them. You're doing all rows of file1, all rows of file 2, ... I'm suggesting looping through them in a different order: first row of every file, second row of every file, ...

Comment: Right, but for the first file i need the first column and second but the rest only second, the first column data will be the same for all files used.

Comment: The first file is handled with this line `outFields = dataLine.split(",")[0:2]`. Notice that the inner for loop skips the first file.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally you want to loop over all input files simultaneously the way `zip` does with iterators.

This example illustrates the pattern without the distraction of files and csvs:

```
file_row_col = [[['1A1', '1A2'],  # File 1, Row A, Column 1 and 2
                 ['1B1', '1B2']], # File 1, Row B, Column 1 and 2
                [['2A1', '2A2'],  # File 2
                 ['2B1', '2B2']],
                [['3A1', '3A2'],  # File 3
                 ['3B1', '3B2']]]

outrows = []

for rows in zip(*file_row_col):
    outrow = [rows[0][0]] # Column 1 of the first file
    for row in rows:
        outrow.extend(row[1:]) # Only Column 2 and on
    outrows.append(outrow)

# outrows is now [['1A1', '1A2', '2A2', '3A2'],
#                 ['1B1', '1B2', '2B2', '3B2']]
```

The key to this is the transformation done by `zip(*file_row_col)`.

Now let's reimplement this pattern with actual files. I'm going to use the `csv` library make reading and writing the csvs easier and safer.

```
import csv

infilenames = ['1.csv','2.csv','3.csv']
outfilename = 'result.csv'

with open(outfilename, 'wb') as out: 
    outcsv = csv.writer(out)
    infiles = []
    # We can't use `with` with a list of resources, so we use
    # try...finally the old-fashioned way instead.
    try:
        incsvs = []
        for infilename in infilenames:
            infile = open(infilename, 'rb')
            infiles.append(infile)
            incsvs.append(csv.reader(infile))
        for inrows in zip(*incsvs):
            outrow = [inrows[0][0]] # Column 1 of file 1
            for inrow in inrows:
                outrow.extend(inrow[1:])
            outcsv.writerow(outrow)
    finally:
        for infile in infiles:
            infile.close()
```

Given these input files:

```
#1.csv
1A1,1A2
1B1,1B2

#2.csv
2A1,2A2
2B1,2B2

#3.csv
3A1,3A2
3B1,3B2
```

the code produces this `result.csv`:

```
1A1,1A2,2A2,3A2
1B1,1B2,2B2,3B2
```